# Installation CloudStack on Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, apache-cloudstack

I want to install CloudStack 4.2.0 on my 32 bit ubuntu in virtual box. It is possible?
And advantages/disadvantages of this from real machine?
Thanks.

Comment: This question seems more admin that development, but I've no idea why it was down voted.  If you've user questions, try the [Apache CloudStack user mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html)

Answer (score 2):

I presume that you're talking about running the Apache CloudStack management server in a 32-bit virtual machine that runs in Virtual Box.

To do anything meaningful with CloudStack, you need at least one hypervisor to control.  To avoid the need for hardware, many CloudStack developers use [DevCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/DevCloud).  DevCloud comes with configuration scripts that make it easier for a beginner to setup the Apache CloudStack management server.

One issue is memory.  If the O/S running VirtualBox is 32-bit, you'll only have 3 gigs of RAM for user processes.  Of this, DevCloud will use about 2 gigs, so memory can be quite tight.

Another issue is networking.  Make sure that there is a network path from the management server to the hypervisors it is meant to control and the storage that it will use for templates (aka secondary storage).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can deploy apache cloudstack on a virtual machine; you can deploy even a whole cloudstack infrastructure on virtual machines provided that you have enough RAM.

You can deploy primary storage, secondary storage, mySQL server and cloudstack management server on Virtual Machines; however the host VMs which will provide the execution environment of your cloudstack instances need to provide nested virtualization which is not available in virtualbox, do use VMWare workstation instead as your type2 hypervisor .

good luck